# How can I repair a pdf file without losing links within it?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am using the following gs command:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/path/to/output.pdf /path/to/input.pdf
```

to repair a pdf file which may have various unclear problems of incompatibility with the pdf specification (e.g. not workable with pdftk, e.g. something maybe called `app` in the implementation of pdftk is null).

But it introduces a new problem. If the main text of a pdf file has clickable links referring elsewhere in the text, such as those clickable titles of chapters and sections in the table of content, the gs command will lose that information. How can I make gs preserve links in a pdf file? Or would you recommend  other software applications other than gs for repairing pdf files without losing links in main text?